# Need Help Troubleshooting Program in C

Tags: c

I need this program to stop asking for flavors when the word "lemon" is said. For some reason, I can't get it to work correctly. I have tried to add an "if" statement for it but it wasn't working out correctly. The code will stop asking for flavor for a split sentence and then will start asking for it again and it will go all the way to 15 flavors instead of stopping at the flavor "lemon".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    void *data;
    int d;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node * createLinkedList(char [][20], int);//function to create linked list for all flavours
node * createLinkedListPrice(int ar[], int);//function to declare linkedlist for all prices

int main(void) {
    int c= 1;//count of input flavors
    char allFlavors[16][20];
    int allPrice[16];
    char ch[] = "lemon"; 
    while(c != 16) {//taking input flavors and prices
        char flavorName[20];
        printf("Enter flavor %d name:", c);
        scanf("%s", flavorName);
        if(!(strcmp(flavorName,ch)) && c > 5) {
            break;
        }
        else if(!(strcmp(flavorName,ch)) && c <= 5) {
            continue;
        }
        int price;
        printf("Enter flavor %d price in $", c);
        scanf("%d", &price);
        strcpy(allFlavors[c], flavorName); //storing all flavors in array of strings
        allPrice[c] = price;//storing all prices in array
        c += 1;//This variable is to keep track of count of input
    }
    while(1) {
        char instruct[5];
        printf("Do u want icecream:");
        scanf("%s", instruct);
        if(!strcmp(instruct,"no"))//If the given instruction is no then break
            break;
        else {//If given instruction is yes then calculate the cost of flavour
            char flav[20];
            int scoops;
            int cost = 0;
            printf("Which flavor do u want\n");
            scanf("%s", flav);
            printf("How many scoops:");
            scanf("%d", &scoops);
            node *head = createLinkedList(allFlavors,c);//calling all flavors function for head
            node *priceHead = createLinkedListPrice(allPrice,c);//calling all price function for head
            while(head != NULL) {//searching for the flavour in the linkedlist
                if(!strcmp(head->data,flav)) {//If flavour is found then add the price to cost
                    cost += (scoops * priceHead->d);
                    break;
                }
                priceHead = priceHead->next;
                head = head->next;
            }
            printf("cost is $%d\n", cost);
        }
    }
}
node * createLinkedList(char allFlavors[][20], int n) {//creates linkedlist of all flavors and returns head
    node * head = NULL;
    node * temp = NULL;
    node * ptr = NULL;
    for(int pd = 1; pd < n; pd++) {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data = allFlavors[pd];
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
            head= temp;
        else {
            ptr=head;
            while(ptr->next!=NULL) {
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next=temp;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
node * createLinkedListPrice(int ar[], int n) {//creates linkedlist of all prices and returns head
    node * head = NULL;
    node * temp = NULL;
    node * ptr = NULL;
    for(int pd = 1; pd < n; pd++) {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->d = ar[pd];
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
            head= temp;
        else {
            ptr=head;
            while(ptr->next!=NULL) {
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next=temp;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: It stops asking for flavors if you enter lemon after flavor 5.

Comment: Because of `&& c > 5`

Comment: Make sure all the flavors you enter are a single word. Otherwise it will try to read the second word when it's expecting the price.

Comment: It's generally best not to use `scanf()` to read user input. You should read a whole line with `fgets()` and then use `sscanf()` to parse the line.

Comment: !(strcmp(flavorName,ch)) returns 0 if the two strings are equal and -1 if the first string is less than the other. This means it returns true even if the two strings do not match. If you want to check for a perfect match just use "strcmp(flavourName, ch) == 0;"

Comment: OT: when calling `scanf()` (and/or any of the `scanf()` family of functions)  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Regarding: `scanf("%s", flav);`  when using the 'input format conversion' specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]`  always include a MAX characters modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoid any buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.  for the current statement, suggest:  `if( scanf("%19s", flav) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for flav failed\n" ); }`

Comment: regarding: ` if(!strcmp(instruct,"no"))`  What happens if the user enters `NO` or just `N`?

Comment: OT: regarding: `temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node))`  1) The returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.  2)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   If not successful, call `perror( "malloc failed" );` so both the `malloc failed` error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`.